# Insert flag of image between country borders?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It would obviously be useful to plot a world map where each country is filled with an image equal to that country's flag.

Here's an example with Lithuania.

[image: flag/country]

Is there an easy way to do this for any given country in an automated way with R and ggplot?

I would imagine we could somehow do this by plotting a large image of the flag somewhere on the plot so that it covers the entire country, and then just "cut off" (or cover over) the parts of the flag that are outside the borders? Probably not a good idea for Chile, but it should work for most reasonably shaped countries, but I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: Relevant package at GitHub: https://github.com/RobertMyles/flagfillr